# Check if an object is a compile-time constant

Tags: dart

I'm trying to write a function that will do the following:

```
isConstant(new Obj()) => false
isConstant(const Obj()) => true
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

At runtime there is no difference between a compile time constant's value and a new object you just created. The difference exists only at compile time.

The only thing you can do is to check whether the object is identical to a known compile time constant.
In this case `(x) => identical(const Object(), x);` would detect the "const Object()" object as different from any "new Object()" created at runtime. That only works if you know all the compile time constants when you write the function, so it's probably not useful. Even going through all top-level/static "const" declarations using mirrors won't find all the constants (and it'd probably be quite wasteful).

What problem are you trying to solve where you need this function?

Comment: In my case the user can only use compile-time constants because I rely on the fact that the objects having the same parameters are identical. So I wanted to warn users if the passed-in object is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: If they are instances of your own class, you could make your constructor only return canonicalized instances. That would mean having a set of already created objects, and when you try to create a new one, the factory constructor looks through the set to see if an equivalent one already, and if so returns that, otherwise it calls a private constructor to create the new object, and inserts it in the set before returning it. Be careful with that, because it means that all instances are kept alive forever, and will never be garbage collected.